# constant Deprecated: preg_replace() error

Tags: callback, wamp

Wordpress 4.5 installed and hosted on WAMP server 2.5

**Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\index.php on line 14**

[SCREENSHOT OF THE WHOLE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9piQ.png)

Comment: Surely Wordpress must have fixed this by now

Comment: Are you using a dodgy addon

Comment: No addons or plugins. Installed it freshly

Answer (score 0):

To stop the message from being produced do this

Using the wampmanager menus ...

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This opens the correct `php.ini` file in your default editor

Find this line (aprox line 451)

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and change it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Thanks,it might have help..I also found that even if the tray icon was green the server was not online, so have click on "Put Online" option to ensure the server is online again.Thanks again :)

Comment: The`online/offline` is not what you think. `Online` means Apache can be accessed by any IP address and `Offline` means APache can only be accessed from the PC running WAMPServer